# My foreign key data type does not match up

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I am using entity code first migrations and it keeps telling me

> Column 'dbo.Users.u_user_id' is not the same data type as referencing
>   column 'PTEInteractiveCourses.ModifyUserId' in foreign key
>   'FK_dbo.PTEInteractiveCourses_dbo.Users_ModifyUserId'. Could not
>   create constraint. See previous errors.

when I try to update-database after I create the migration.  Here is PTEInteractivieCourse:

```
namespace PTEManager.Domain
{
    public class PTEInteractiveCourse
    {
        [Key]
        public Guid PTEInteractiveCourseId { get; set; }

        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        [Required]
        public DateTime ModifyDate { get; set; }

        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        [ForeignKey("ModifyUser")]
        [Required]
        public double ModifyUserId { get; set; }

        public virtual OpsUser ModifyUser { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Package")]
        [ForeignKey("package_nme")]
        [Required]
        public int PackageId { get; set; }

        public virtual Package package_nme { get; set; }

        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        [Display(Name = "")]
        [Required]
        public int Status { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "STCI Course")]
        [ForeignKey("STCICourseName")]
        [Required]
        public Guid STCIProductInteractiveInfoID { get; set; }

        public virtual STCIProductInteractiveInfo STCICourseName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and here is my table:

[image]

Here is my user model just in case:

```
namespace PTEManager.Domain
{
    public partial class OpsUser
    {
        public double u_user_id { get; set; }

        public Guid DepartmentID { get; set; }

        public string email_addr { get; set; }

        public string first_nme { get; set; }

        public string last_nme { get; set; }

        public Guid msrepl_tran_version { get; set; }

        public string status { get; set; }

        public string user_nme { get; set; }

        public int u_branch_id { get; set; }

    }
}
```

and user map:

```
namespace PTEManager.Domain.Mapping
{
    class UserMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<OpsUser>
    {
        public UserMap()
        {
            // Primary Key
            this.HasKey(t => t.u_user_id);

            // Properties
            this.Property(t => t.DepartmentID);

            this.Property(t => t.email_addr)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasMaxLength(50);

            this.Property(t => t.first_nme)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasMaxLength(30);

            this.Property(t => t.last_nme)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasMaxLength(30);

            this.Property(t => t.msrepl_tran_version)
                .IsRequired();

            this.Property(t => t.status)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasMaxLength(1);

            this.Property(t => t.user_nme)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasMaxLength(15);

            this.Property(t => t.u_branch_id)
                .IsRequired();

            // Table & Column Mappings
            this.ToTable("Users");
            this.Property(t => t.u_user_id).HasColumnName("u_user_id");
            this.Property(t => t.DepartmentID).HasColumnName("DepartmentID");
            this.Property(t => t.email_addr).HasColumnName("email_addr");
            this.Property(t => t.first_nme).HasColumnName("first_nme");
            this.Property(t => t.last_nme).HasColumnName("last_nme");
            this.Property(t => t.msrepl_tran_version).HasColumnName("msrepl_tran_version");
            this.Property(t => t.status).HasColumnName("status");
            this.Property(t => t.user_nme).HasColumnName("user_nme");
            this.Property(t => t.u_branch_id).HasColumnName("u_branch_id");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If I'm reading your code correctly, the FK in `OpsUser` is a `double`, and the PK in your table is a `numeric(10,0)`.  These are definitely not the same data type, hence your error.

Comment: @MartinParkin, I now tried a long, decimal, and int and it also does not work.  There is no numeric type in C#

Answer (score 1):

To build upon what Martin Parkin is saying, your datatypes are not matching up between your entity and your database. I would also suggest not using `double` as a PK or FK in most cases. Realistically you would want this to be an integer or a long.

numeric(10,0) = integer

numeric(19,0) = long

Comment: dumbknee, I changed it to a long and I am still getting this error.